# Could not find generator cucumber:feature

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

When I try to run `rails generate cucumber:feature`, I get an error - `Could not find generator cucumber:feature.`

In my gemfile:

```
group :test do
  gem 'cucumber-rails'

  # database_cleaner is not required, but highly recommended
  gem 'database_cleaner'
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cucumber generate command should looks like

```
rails generate cucumber:install
```

after that go to `features` folder

and create any file name like `article_search.feature` within write your features ,scenarios

look like as https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-rails/tree/master/features

for more environment fix

check `features/support/env.rb`

and for your step definitions go to
`features/step_definitions` folder

look like this https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-rails/tree/master/features/step_definitions

Comment: Sorry, I haven't written correctly name generator. I try to run `cucumber:feature` generator. `cucumber:install` I ran before.

Comment: you can manually create a file in features folder name like `articleas_search.feature` please follow http://asciicasts.com/episodes/155-beginning-with-cucumber

Comment: thanks. I thought that I can create feature file with help specific generator

Comment: ralis generate cucumber:install worked for me once I added gem 'cucumber-rails' to the development group in my gemfile